# remove duplicate entries while executing repeated job to save json data in mongo

Tags: json, mongodb, grails, caching, duplicates

I am having following structure currently present in my database, i am executing a service to fetch data from REST api and storing it to my database , so that i can use it to display it frequently on UI as like caching a data

```
db.countDetails.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5670xxxx"),
    "totalProjectCount" : 53,
    "activeProjectCount" : 29,
    "completedProjectCount" : 1,
    "userCount" : 85
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5670ea97f14c717a903e8423"),
    "totalProjectCount" : 48,
    "activeProjectCount" : 41,
    "completedProjectCount" : 0,
    "userCount" : 123
}
```

My collection is going to remain same only values will be going to change, so please suggest me a way in which i can place the updated values in mongo and at the same time i can fetch data on my UI

my new values might be like

```
db.countDetails.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5670xxxx"),
    "totalProjectCount" : 23,
    "activeProjectCount" : 17,
    "completedProjectCount" : 1,
    "userCount" : 60
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5670ea97f14c717a903e8423"),
    "totalProjectCount" : 45,
    "activeProjectCount" : 40,
    "completedProjectCount" : 0,
    "userCount" : 113
}
```

function to fetch data from REST api

```
def getCount(String companyName, String apiKey) {

    //declaration section
    List returnList           = []
    int totalProjectCount     = 0                                                         //variable to hold total no of projects value
    int activeProjectCount    = 0                                                         //variable to hold total active projects value
    int completedProjectCount = 0                                                         //variable to hold total completed projects value
    int userCount             = 0                                                         //variable to hold total active user count
    String userAPIKey         = apiKey                                                    //user API key for authorization
    String method             = 'GET'                                                     //method of request

    String totalProjectURL    = "https://"+ companyName + ".teamwork.com/projects.json?status=ALL"     // Url to access All projects
    StringBuilder out         = getConnection(totalProjectURL, method, userAPIKey)        //String builder to hold result
    //catching result into json
    JSONObject object         = new JSONObject(out.toString())                            //JSON object to store String in json format
    totalProjectCount         = object.projects.length()

    String activeProjectCountURL = "https://"+ companyName + ".teamwork.com/projects.json?status=ACTIVE"        // Url to access Active projects
    out                          = getConnection(activeProjectCountURL, method, userAPIKey)
    //catching result into json
    object                       = new JSONObject(out.toString())
    activeProjectCount           = object.projects.length()

    String completedProjectCountURL = "https://"+ companyName + ".teamwork.com/projects.json?status=COMPLETED"  // Url to access completed projects
    out                          = getConnection(completedProjectCountURL, method, userAPIKey)
    //catching result into json
    object                       = new JSONObject(out.toString())
    completedProjectCount        = object.projects.length()

    String peopleURL             = "https://"+ companyName + ".teamwork.com/people.json"                       // Url to access total active users
    out                          = getConnection(peopleURL, method, userAPIKey)
    //catching result into json
    object                       = new JSONObject(out.toString())
    userCount                    = object.people.length()

    Map returnMap = [:]
    returnMap.put('totalProjectCount', totalProjectCount)
    returnMap.put('activeProjectCount', activeProjectCount)
    returnMap.put('completedProjectCount', completedProjectCount)
    returnMap.put('userCount', userCount)

    addCount(returnMap, 'curo', 'countDetails')
    println('project count successfully saved.')
}
```

function to add countDetails to mongo

```
def addCount(Map userMap, String dbName, String collectionName) {

    try {
        DB db = mongo.getDB(dbName)
        DBCollection table = db.getCollection(collectionName)

        table.insert(userMap as BasicDBObject)
        def srvcResponseObj = [ responseStatus : "pass", responseCode : 200 ]
        return srvcResponseObj
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        println "Exception related to Mongo add record"
        e.printStackTrace()
        def srvcResponseObj = [ responseStatus : "fail", responseCode: 400 ]
        return srvcResponseObj
    }
}
```

function to fetch data from mongo

```
def fetchCountDetails(String databaseName, String collectionName) {

    println 'inside fetch count details'
    try {
        DB db = mongo.getDB(databaseName)
        DBCollection table = db.getCollection(collectionName)
        DBCursor cursor = table.find()
        Map returnCountMap = [:]
        List temp = []

        int cursorCounter = 0
        while(cursor.hasNext()) {

            Map temporaryMap = [:]
            BasicDBObject doc = (BasicDBObject) cursor.next()
            doc.remove('_id')
            temp.add(doc)
            cursorCounter++
        }
        returnCountMap.put('totalProjectCount', temp.totalProjectCount.sum())
        returnCountMap.put('activeProjectCount',temp.activeProjectCount.sum())
        returnCountMap.put('completedProjectCount',temp.completedProjectCount.sum())
        returnCountMap.put('userCount',temp.userCount.sum())

        if(cursorCounter>1)
            println "Multiple objects found for eventID"
        if(cursorCounter==0)
            println "No objects found for eventID"
        return returnCountMap
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        println "Exception related to Mongo >> fetchUserDetails"
        e.printStackTrace()
        def srvcResponseObj = [ responseStatus : "fail", responseCode: 400 ]
        return srvcResponseObj
    }
}
```

now i am making request to REST api after fixed amount of interval and my response gets changed in terms of values, but if i call the add function again and again my documents get duplicated in mongodb and my expected result is that my new values gets reflected in mongodb

Comment: why don't you set unique key for any of the field?

Comment: What is the criteria based upon you want to update the values. Or is it like your collection will be going to have two documents only at a time?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use on-the-fly aggregations instead?

Comment: @SandeepPoonia as i have mentioned only my values are going to change the structure of the collection going to remain same, i wont mind replacing the old values which are not changed, but i just need to have a same collection with new values

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg as i am new to mongodb i don't have much knowledge about on-the-fly aggregation it would be great if you have example, anyway thanks for comment i ll go through it

Comment: @MariyaJames i am using a function to insert data in mongodb, and as a parameter i am passing a list which contains maps of lists & plain <key,value> and i am having thousands of records that is why i didn't thought about primary key. because i think it would be a tedious job to check and update

Comment: @AmarMagar Your collection have two documents in example. So is there any criteria based upon which you want update these two documents or you just want to remove these two documents and then add two new. Or the Id field is being maintained by you.

Comment: @SandeepPoonia yes right i want to remove these both documents from collection and have new one with same structure possibly with different values and i am not maintaining id field anywhere thanks for the reply

Comment: Please show sample documents of projects and users, and I will show you what you could do using aggregations.

Comment: After you have fetched the data from REST, fetch data from mongo, iterate over it, and update its content, leaving id as it is.